# Null Pointer Exception in Java and not sure why

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have been writing a Java program - Specifically a Bukkit plugin, although that has nothing to do with the question - and for a reason I cannot see I am getting a NullPointerException. Excerpted below is the code at which there is an error. `getPath()` is well-tested and yields the correct directory - That is, the one in which the config file should be in. the config file is created, and should have been written to. The tester file I have has been successfully created, and so should the config file.

```
File config = new File(getPath("config"));
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(config));
skipLines(11, in);
if(in.readLine().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {   //Exception is here
    System.out.println("Successfully wrote to config file");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Failed to write text correctly to config file");
}
in.close();
```

The whole thing is enclosed in a try/catch statement. 
If you need any more info, just ask and I will be happy to provide. 
NOTE: The file is working just fine - When I check manually the file has writing on it. That's why the problem exists. 
The code that writes to the file is below:

```
File exConfig = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "configExample");
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(config));
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(exConfig));
for(int i = 1; i <= configLength; i++) {
    out.println(in.readLine());
}
out.flush();
out.close();
System.out.println("Successfully wrote defaults to config");
```

`configLength` is a variable equal to the number of lines in the config. I have tested it and it works.
There may be something odd there. The file called "configExample" is as follows:

```
########################################
#  hPlugin is written by newbiedoodle  #
########################################
#   -----  Plugin config file  -----   #
########################################
hPlugin
v.0.3
NOTE: Do not edit the config file besides changing the values - it may result in errors.
--------------
Enable hPlugin?
true
Strikes before being banned?
3
Godmode?
true
First time running the plugin?
true
Curse protection?
true
Emergency shelter?
true
Path building?
true
Blocked words/phrases (Separate with colon (:)):
shit:fuck:damn:bitch:hell
```

As you can see, this SHOULD be more than 11 lines... And if the 11th line isn't "true" then it still shouldn't cause an error. 
 
Well, after a little bit of fooling around, I got it to work... Turns out, I had a variable screwed up because a function had a filename hard-coded into it rather than set to the variable I was trying to pass. Thanks for all the help though!

Comment: can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: You say the file "should" be there. Is it? It has more than 11 lines?

Comment: @Dchan
By stacktrace I mean what I get from `e.printStackStrace()`, so here it is:
`java.lang.NullPointerException  at minecraft.hplugin.main.mainClass.main(mainClass.java:269)`

@madth3
The file IS there, I manually checked and it seems like it should work. The file is 25 lines give or take 1 as I counted it rather sloppily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is obvious, there is nothing to read from your **BufferedReader**. Thus `in.readLine()` returns null, Thus invoking `in.readLine.equalIgnorecase()` returns NullPointerException.

you should first check if BufferedReader.readLine() returns null, before you proceed.

```
if(in.readLine().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {   //Exception is here
```

should be

```
String line=null;
while((line=in.readLine())!=null) {   //if in.readLine()  returns null, the condition fails
if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
     //do your stuff
}
}
```

Comment: No, the line should be written - I check the file manually and it worked perfectly. That's why I have a question. If it was just that the file was empty, then I would be able to fix it, but it's not.

Comment: @NickHartley you are calling readLine on bufferedreader, not file.i dont think there is readLine() method in File class. buffredReader.readLine() returns a string, if the file is empty it returns null. check the doc here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

Comment: @NickHartley if your file is not empty, can you post the skipLine() method, maybe there is something fishy there

Comment: First, you have NO idea how annoying your name it to type :P
Second, it turns out I had a file hard-coded into a function I was using, and that's what was causing the problem.
Third, I'm pretty sure that I was calling readLine() on a BufferedReader. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: @NickHartley hahaha, you dont need to type my name, if you leave a comment i get the notification :P

Comment: BTW this is the closest to the right answer I got, so I am accepting it.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know that... Well now I do XD
Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

readLine() returns null, and then you call equalsIgnore on that null value.
separate that calls, and check to be not null.